# Proving Subspace Is Path connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ as set of $2\times2$ complex matrics with determinant $1$, consider as subspace of the metric space $M_2(\mathbb C)$ of $2\times2$ complex matrices. Prove $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ is path connected.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I used a lemma in liner algebra so i want to find function for $\alpha(t) , \beta(t) , \gama(t) $ in $\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
\alpha(t) & \beta(t)  \\ 0 & \gamma(t)  \end{array} \right]$ to show $\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
\alpha & \beta  \\ 0 & \gamma  \end{array} \right]$ can be connected to $\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1  \end{array} \right]$.

Comment: You can also see my idea in this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566084/find-path-path-connected

Comment: If you know polar decomposition then try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the problem in greater generality. Suppose $A$ is a square matrix, and $B$ is  obtained from $A$ by adding a multiple of $i$th row to $j$th row ($i\ne j$). As you know, $\det B=\det A$. A key observation for this problem is that all matrices on the line through $A$ and $B$ have the same determinant. Indeed, each of them is obtained from $A$ in the aforementioned way.

The above works the same for columns, of course.

Using the  row/column operations described above, you can bring any $SL_n$ matrix $A$ to diagonal form $D$. This results in a piecewise linear path from $A$ to $D$, lying in $SL_n$.

A diagonal matrix  can be connected to identity as follows: connect each diagonal entry  $a_{jj}$ to $1$ by some curve $\gamma_j$ in $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$, and consider the matrix with diagonal $$\left(\gamma_1(t),\dots,\gamma_{n-1}(t),\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\gamma_j(t)^{-1}\right)$$